# URL error : To get JSON from a WebService on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, url

I'm a begginer on Android Studio and I have a problem to call Json from a WebService.
I use this code to try to get my data :

```
public static ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    try {
        String myurl = "http://localhost/MyWebService/getUsers";

        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        String result = InputStreamOperations.InputStreamToString(inputStream);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("UserDB"));

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(array.getString(i));
            User user = new User(obj.getString("name"), obj.getString("firstname"));
            users.add(user);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return users;
}
```

But on debug mod, it stops on "URL url = new URL(myurl);" 
Event Log message : "ConcurrentModificationException: null" 
Have you an idea about the reason of this problem please ?
(sorry about my English ^^')

 Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does it occur only in debug mode?

Comment: check out web service tutorials on google.

Comment: Yes, my method is called when I click on a button.
When I'm running my app, the button does nothing while he should add data on a listView.

Comment: Are you able to access this? Then post output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to connect from the Emulator to a WebService hosted on you local machine you have to call `10.0.2.2` instead of `localhost` ([android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)), because `localhost` would refer to the emulator itself.

Additionally you require the internet permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thanks
I catch this Exception now : EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: Have you adapted the two things and is the permission on the [right place](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#permissions)? Because the exception seems to be more related to handling of (external) storage

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Retrofit library [here](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). Its a great tool for handling rest web service communication and avoid cumbersome parsing code. Just add the dependencies, in Android Studio would be :

> compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
>
> compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'

The example on that link is quite straightforward to get u started.